# JPA correct way to handle detached entity state in case of exceptions/rollback

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ejb, jpa-2.1

I have this class and I tought three ways to handle detached entity state in case of persistence exceptions (which are handled elsewhere):

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class EntityBean implements Serializable
{
    @EJB
    private PersistenceService service;

    private Document entity;

    public void update()
    {
        // HANDLING 1. ignore errors
        service.transact(em -> 
        {
            entity = em.merge(entity);

            // some other code that modifies [entity] properties:
            // entity.setCode(...);
            // entity.setResposible(...);
            // entity.setSecurityLevel(...);

        });  // an exception may be thrown on method return (rollback), 
        // but [entity] has already been reassigned with a "dirty" one.

        //------------------------------------------------------------------

        // HANDLING 2. ensure entity is untouched before flush is ok
        service.transact(em -> 
        {
            Document managed = em.merge(entity);

            // some other code that modifies [managed] properties:
            // managed.setCode(...);
            // managed.setResposible(...);
            // managed.setSecurityLevel(...);

            em.flush(); // an exception may be thrown here (rollback)
            // forcing method exit without [entity] being reassigned.

            entity = managed;

        }); // an exception may be thrown on method return (rollback), 
        // but [entity] has already been reassigned with a "dirty" one.

        //------------------------------------------------------------------

        // HANDLING 3. ensure entity is untouched before whole transaction is ok
        AtomicReference<Document> reference = new AtomicReference<>();
        service.transact(em -> 
        {
            Document managed = em.merge(entity);

            // some other code that modifies [managed] properties:
            // managed.setCode(...);
            // managed.setResposible(...);
            // managed.setSecurityLevel(...);

            reference.set(managed);

        }); // an exception may be thrown on method return (rollback), 
        // and [entity] is safe, it's not been reassigned yet.

        entity = reference.get();
    }

    ...
}
```

`PersistenceService#transact(Consumer<EntityManager> consumer)` can throw unchecked exceptions.

The goal is to maintain the state of the entity aligned with the state of the database, even in case of exceptions (prevent entity to become "dirty" after transaction fail).

- Method 1. is obviously naive and doesn't guarantee coherence.
- Method 2. asserts that nothing can go wrong after flushing.
- Method 3. prevents the new entity assigment if there's an exception in the whole transaction

**Questions:**

1. Is method 3. really safer than method 2.?
2. Are there cases where an exception is thrown between `flush` [excluded] and `commit` [included]?
3. Is there a standard way to handle this common problem?

Thank you

---

Note that I'm already able to rollback the transaction and close the EntityManager (`PersistenceService#transact` will do it gracefully), but I need to solve *database state and the business objects do get out of sync. Usually this is not a problem*. In my case this is **the** problem, because exceptions are usually generated by `BeanValidator` (those on JPA side, not on JSF side, for *computed* values that *depends* on user inputs) and I want the user to input correct values and try again, **without losing the values he entered before**.

Side note: I'm using Hibernate 5.2.1

---

this is the PersistenceService (CMT)

```
@Stateless
@Local
public class PersistenceService implements Serializable
{
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public void transact(Consumer<EntityManager> consumer)
    {
        consumer.accept(em);
    }
}
```

---

#### @DraganBozanovic

That's it! Great explanation for point 1. and 2.

I'd just love you to elaborate a little more on point 3. and give me some advice on real-world use case.

> However, I would definitely not use AtomicReference or similar cumbersome constructs. Java EE, Spring and other frameworks and application containers support declaring transactional methods via annotations: Simply use the result returned from a transactional method.

When you have to modify a single entity, the transactional method would just take the detached entity as parameter and return the updated entity, easy.

```
public Document updateDocument(Document doc)
{
    Document managed = em.merge(doc);
    // managed.setXxx(...);
    // managed.setYyy(...);

    return managed;
}
```

But when you need to modify more than one in a single transaction, the method can become a real pain:

```
public LinkTicketResult linkTicket(Node node, Ticket ticket)
{
    LinkTicketResult result = new LinkTicketResult();

    Node managedNode = em.merge(node);
    result.setNode(managedNode);

    // modify managedNode

    Ticket managedTicket = em.merge(ticket);
    result.setTicket(managedTicket);

    // modify managedTicket

    Remark managedRemark = createRemark(...);
    result.setRemark(managedemark);

    return result;
}
```

In this case, my pain:

1. I have to create a dedicated transactional method (maybe a dedicated `@EJB` too)
2. That method will be called only once (will have just one caller) - is a "one-shot" non-reusable public method. Ugly.
3. I have to create the dummy class `LinkTicketResult`
4. That class will be instantiated only once, in that method - is "one-shot"
5. The method could have many parameters (or another dummy class `LinkTicketParameters`)
6. JSF controller actions, in most cases, will just call a EJB method, extract  updated entities from returned container and reassign them to local fields
7. My code will be steadily polluted with "one-shotters", too many for my taste.

Probably I'm not seeing something big that's just in front of me, I'll be very grateful if you can point me in the right direction.

Comment: @downvoter would you mind to explain?

Comment: I have not downvoted, but i would imagine it is because of not compilable code.

Comment: @tak3shi it's a code fragment adapted as a sample, if someone downvoted for this reason I'm sorry for his limited mind ;)

Comment: I don't get the whole thing.... Is the EM user or container managed ? What is its scope ? application ?

Comment: @Gab the em is CMT. The controller is a JSF `@ViewScoped` `@ManagedBean`. See updated question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. **Is method 3. really safer than method 2.?**

   Yes. Not only is it safer (see point 2), but it is conceptually more correct, as you change transaction-dependent state only when you proved that the related transaction has succeeded.
2. **Are there cases where an exception is thrown between flush [excluded] and commit [included]?**

   Yes. For example:

   1. [LockMode.OPTIMISTIC](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/LockMode.html#OPTIMISTIC):

      > Optimistically assume that transaction will not experience contention
      >   for entities. **The entity version will be verified near the transaction
      >   end.**

      It would be neither performant nor practically useful to check optimistick lock violation during each flush operation within a single transaction.
   2. Deferred integrity constraints (enforced at commit time in db). Not used often, but are an illustrative example for this case.
   3. Later maintenance and refactoring. You or somebody else may later introduce additional changes after the last explicit call to flush.
3. **Is there a standard way to handle this common problem?**

   Yes, I would say that your third approach is the standard one: Use the results of a complete and successful transaction.

   However, I would definitely not use `AtomicReference` or similar cumbersome constructs. Java EE, Spring and other frameworks and application containers support declaring transactional methods via annotations: Simply use the result returned from a transactional method.

Comment: Thank you! I elaborated a bit the point 3, I'll be grateful if you could give some *pratical* advice in real-world cases.

Comment: @MicheleMariotti That is already a bit opinion based. I think that it is more suitable for a separate question on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/. I would say that a one-shotter separate class for method result is still more readable than one-shotter `AtomicReference`s scattered throughout the code. Of course, you know best your use cases and conventions used in your projects.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is entirely to the point, but there is only one way to recover after exceptions: rollback and close the EM. From https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-basics-issues

> An exception thrown by the Entity Manager means you have to rollback
>   your database transaction and close the EntityManager immediately
>   (discussed later in more detail). If your EntityManager is bound to
>   the application, you have to stop the application. Rolling back the
>   database transaction doesn't put your business objects back into the
>   state they were at the start of the transaction. This means the
>   database state and the business objects do get out of sync. Usually
>   this is not a problem, because exceptions are not recoverable and you
>   have to start over your unit of work after rollback anyway.

-- EDIT--
Also see http://piotrnowicki.com/2013/03/jpa-and-cmt-why-catching-persistence-exception-is-not-enough/

ps: downvote is not mine.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the point; I'm already able to rollback the transaction and close the EntityManager (`PersistenceService#transact` will do it gracefully), but I need to solve *database state and the business objects do get out of sync. Usually this is not a problem*. In my case this is **the** problem, because exceptions are usually generated by `BeanValidator` and I want the user to input correct values and try again, **without losing the values he entered before**.

Comment: @MicheleMariotti I do not see any reason why you should loose the values after a BeanValidator exception. Your question does not demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @tak3shi I update the question to better explain what in the code causes the problem. I'll lose the value when a "dirty" entity is assigned to the [entity] field, because the "dirty" one is not mergeable anymore (i.e. has an incremented `@Version` value).